# Trouble in compiling Mono from source on one machine and install it Different machine

Tags: c#, deployment, mono

I want to create parallel mono environment on users' machine but i faced a major issue that it will be installed on that machine on which it was compiled.

**I don't want to compile mono source on users' machine, I want to compile it on one machine and distribute it to users for installation.**

**Please help!!!!! and please suggest is it possible or not?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Copy compiled mono folder with preserving symlinks on another machine.
so that you can use that mono instead off native mono which is pre-installed in user's machine.`

`#> cp -rvf --preserve=links /source/compiled_mono /destination/othermachine`